# AutoMapper - Map child property hiding base class property

Tags: c#, inheritance, automapper, parent-child, member-hiding

I'm encountering a quite stupid issue while trying to map a class to a derived class using **AutoMapper** with C#.

These are my classes:

```
class BaseParent {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public BaseChild Child { get; set; }
}

class BaseChild {
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

class DerivedParent : BaseParent {
    public new DerivedChild Child { get; set; }
}

class DerivedChild : BaseChild { }
```

In particular, what I'm trying to achieve is that all the properties of the mapped class are correctly set. The issue is that the `Child` property of the mapped class is not set and remains *null*.

This is the mapping configuration I'm using:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
        cfg.CreateMap<BaseChild, DerivedChild>();
        cfg.CreateMap<BaseParent, DerivedParent>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Child, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Child));
    });
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Actually is not correct to say that `Child` property remains *null*.
Debugging the code I can see that there are 2 child properties with the same name because of the `new` modifier used to hide the parent one.

Anyway, the property I need is still *null*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're looking at it correctly?

Given the following config:

```
// Arrange
var mapper = new Mapper(new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<BaseChild, DerivedChild>();
    cfg.CreateMap<BaseParent, DerivedParent>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Child, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Child));
}));
var baseParent = new BaseParent { Name = "A", Child = new BaseChild { Age = 1 } };

// Act
var derived = mapper.Map<DerivedParent>(baseParent);
```

I can assure you that:

- `derived.Child` is certainly `not null`
- It is of type `DerivedChild`
- The hidden `BaseChild` is `null`

Which you can see in the following ([see working Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hOBW5p)):

```
// Assert
Assert.IsNotNull(derived);
Assert.IsInstanceOf<DerivedParent>(derived);

// The 'new' Child property is not null
Assert.IsNotNull(derived.Child);
Assert.IsInstanceOf<DerivedChild>(derived.Child);

// The hidden property should be null
Assert.IsNull(((BaseParent)derived).Child);
```

Comment: Actually you're right. I was testing such situation on LinqPad and that's what I see: https://pasteboard.co/JAALOHB.png.

Comment: Funny you mention LinqPad, cause that's what I tried it on first time, and saw what you're seeing. Which led me to investigate further, including dumping the [execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Understanding-your-mapping.html) - which definitively looked like it *should* have worked. I say this might've been a problem with LinqPad.